# Is there an easy way to place grid in plot to background R

Tags: r, plot, grid

I have to plot grid in my plots. I have found one solution for this purpose

```
barplot(1:50)
grid()
box()
par(new = TRUE)
barplot(1:50)
```

And following is the plot
[image]
I am ok with it. But why I should call barplot twice. Is there some easy way to move grid to background ?

I have faced following problem is my plot (boxplot)

```
png("test2.png")
bm = boxplot(exuper, fuper, super, tuper, dat$uper, outline = F, names=names, panel.first = grid())
box()    
dev.off()
```

AND THE ERROR is

```
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
> box()
Error in box() : plot.new has not been called yet
```

Comment: From the linked post, try `barplot(1:50, panel.first = grid())`

Comment: Why are you assigning your `boxplot` call to a variable?

Comment: Its NA. So it has not impect.